# No GUI after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, upgrade, compiz, fsck, 15.10

I upgraded from 14.04 LTS to 15.04 to 15.10 today.

To do this I used `sudo do-release-upgrade`. The upgrade to 15.04 went without any problems, but after upgrading to 15.10 I only get to console/recovery mode when booting.

I got a warning from `compiz` when trying to launch `unity` about a missing display (like "compiz couldn't open display" and "com.upstart.ubuntu doesn't exist"). Afterwards I removed the nvidia drivers `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`, but now I get a screen with `fsck` checking my drive, but it seems stuck.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidea*
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
sudo apt-get install nouveau-firmware
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo shutdown -r now
```

(xserver-xorg was also missing completely)

Comment: You must mean nvidia

Answer (score 0):

Distinct of command "update-manager -c", the command "sudo do-release-upgrade -p -m desktop" need specify the edition of distro [desktop] or [server].

The server edition was installed, of course, without desktop environment.