# Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

Tags: boot, kernel, shared-library

I had an issue in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/share` I tried to fix it, but after I rebooted the computer I got these error messages and I couldn't run the computer again.

```
/sbin/init:error while loading shared libraries: libip4tc.so.0:   
 cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory   
[timestamp] end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
```

Comment: If you re-install (refer @user535733's answer, I'd suggest using 'something else' & **not-format** your partition(s) whilst using existing. It'll cause the installer to take note of your installed packages. erase system directories & install system, then add-back your additional packages (*you didn't give details of your release, so I've made assumptions that may not apply in your case*).  It doesn't touch user files (unless you format which will cause them to be wiped), and is very quick.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two problems. Read from the bottom upwards, the first problem seems that your kernel cannot start properly.

This may be very easy to workaround - simply select another kernel [at the GRUB prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) ([Alternative method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770999/)).

The second problem is that you seem to have broken iptables, your system's firewall. This is indeed a problem, as it may prevent your system from booting properly. Happily, it also seems fairy easy to fix IF your system can be booted (see above):

`sudo apt install --reinstall iptables`

If your system still cannot be booted, then it looks to me that you have two choices:

1. Boot from a LiveUSB, [chroot your system](https://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation), and then reinstall the `iptables package`. This method is NOT for beginners, and makes sense for intermediate/advanced users with a LOT of customizations that they don't want to lose.
2. Boot from a LiveUSB, backup your data, and reinstall your Ubuntu system. for most newer users, this is going to be faster and easier.

We don't know what you did...but don't do that again.